# SonarQube Incremental mode gives different results on different machines with same code

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am running a new sonar server with one project and one quality profile.
I have a "runner" machine that continuously running full scans (after getting the latest code)
and the developers machines where they would like to run incremental analyses before checking-in.

when running an incremental on the "runner" machine without making any changes I get 0 issues as expected (but I am also getting a lot of "resolved" issues - what is the deal with that? I expected to get 0 new and 0 resolved since I changed NOTHING).

BUT, when running incremental on the developer machine (after getting the latest code) I am getting a huge number of new issues, even though they also made no changes to the code.

to make sure I am not making any mistakes, I used TFS to compare the two project directories (on the runner and on the dev local machines, the folders that the analysis uses) - and proved that both are the same (except for the sonar generated files)

so to sum it up:

1. what could be the cause for such a behavior?
2. why would I get resolved issues if I did not make any changes to the code?
3. could it have anything to do with machine clocks? (i am desperate...)

If you would tell me that there is no change in hell that such a problem can occur, then I would go back and check myself, but I am running such a simple configuration that I don't think that I am missing anything.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should check and compare the analysis logs in both cases to be able to figure out where the difference(s) is (are).

Comment: thank you for your help, I will try that. do you have any pointers, perhaps something special that I should watch for? should I run with --debug?

Comment: Running analysis in simple mode should be enough to start with. Then if you need to dig further, you can indeed add "-Dsonar.verbose=true".

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am having the same problem, between 50 and 300 new issues are reported in files no one has modified.

Comment: @cdman52, I think I am getting there. first of all thanks all, I feel silly for not digging into the output earlier. anyway, at least for the C# plugin, I noticed that Gendarme inspects the binaries of your project (I saw this from comparing the logs), and since in my runner server (Where i run regular analyses) I wasn't building the project, it simply would not run, yielding different results. I am not sure I got everything, I still need to work through the logs and compare, I suspect there are also other differences. I will report more after I am done.